# Submit form via ajax and show error

Tags: forms

I have a simple question but after and hour searching I can't find the right answer.

I'm trying to submit a custom form via ajax but I don't know which is the right way to show validation error or where to show them.

My initial code is this:

```
function contactar_profesor_form($form, &$form_state,$uid) {
  $form['from'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => '',
    '#markup' => '<h3>Escríbeme un mensaje</h3>',
  );
  $form['nombre'] = array(
    '#title' => t(''),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 255,
    '#maxlength' => 255,
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Escribe tu nombre',),
  );
  $form['mensaje'] = array(
    '#title' => t(''),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Deja tu mensaje. Recuerda que puedes indicarle tu número de teléfono o email para que el profesor contacte contigo',),
  );
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Enviar'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'contactar_profesor_callback',
      'wrapper' => "contacto-wrapper-$uid",
      'method' => 'replace',
    ),
  );
  $form['uid'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $uid);
  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'contactar-profesor-form';
  return $form;
}

function contactar_profesor_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!$form_state['values']['nombre']) {
    // show errors??? how???
  }
  return '<div id="contacto-wrapper-'.$form_state['values']['uid'].'"></div>';
}
```

I have tried with drupal_set_message but it doesn't appear.

Thanks!

Comment: drupal_set_message should work. could you please show the code how you used it.

Comment: yes... I think the problem is with noty messages. It shows four times....

Comment: I would put validation in a validation function, and use form_set_error(), otherwise the form won't degrade well (when JS is off).